# upper bound for Ito integral of deterministic integrand

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

It is well known that Ito integrals with respect to a Brownian motion cannot be defined pathwise because the Brownian motion has infinite 1st order variation. These integrals are defined as limits of simple integrals in a $L^2$ sense. Now, I was interested in the following: If $f$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[a,b]$, is it possible to bound the integral $\int_a^b f(t) dW_t$ for almost every path $\omega$ (if $W$ is a brownian motion)? I found in the link below on equation (4.33) page 49:

http://www.ems.bbk.ac.uk/for_students/msc_finEng/math_methods/lecture34.pdf

that it is possible to get for almost every $\omega$:
\begin{align*}
& \left | \int_a^b f(t) dW_t \right| \leq 2(1+b-a) (||f||+||f'||) \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |W(t)|,
\end{align*}
where $||f||:=\sup_{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)|$, $||f'||:=\sup_{t \in [a,b]} |f'(t)|$.

I am honestly a little dubious about the latter upper bound. I tried to look for some other literature on Ito integrals but they almost always do the same thing, i.e. constructing it as a limit in a $L^2$ sense. I didn't find anything in the specific case of integrals wit respect to a deterministic and smooth integrand $f$.

Comment: This is long subject. It depends on your assumptions, in general this type of integrals (Riemann-Stieltjes) have along and heavy history. In 1924, Wiener introduce the concept of double variation after that concept of $ p $-variation is developed until Yong and Love proved their interesting results in 1936. I have worked and studied a lot about this subject (some published article). In Google,  you may write "approximating Riemann-Stieltjes integral" and here I would like to mention that my Prof. Sever S. Dragomir (australia) published several ten papers about approx. Riemann-Stieltjes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, I was very stupid. We can just apply Ito's formula and get:
\begin{align*}
& \int_a^b f(t)dW_t=f(b)W_b-f(a)W_a-\int_a^b W_t f'(t)dt.
\end{align*}
This yields that indeed we can find the desired pathwise upper bound of $\int_a^b f(t)dW_t$ in terms of $||f||$, $||f'||$, $\sup_{t \in [a,b]}|W(t)|$.

Answer (score 1):

If your $f$ is continuous differentiable then this ito integral is a pathwise RS integral then of course you can find a bound